# What are the size of each Android screen

Tags: android

I'm looking for all sizes of the content area of each android size:

- QVGA (240x320)
- WQVGA400 (240x400)
- WQVGA432 (240x432)
- HVGA (320x480)
- WVGA800 (480x800)
- WVGA854 (480x854)

What I mean by "content area" is the screen without the notification bar. I couldn't find this information anywhere (either the content area sizes or the height of the notification bar).

While I could load all size in the emulator and calculate the size for each screen, I'm sure somebody else has already done it. :)

Comment: And what do you need that for? I'm almost certain that you're using the wrong approach, whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What everyone here's trying to say is that a simple list of all the preset emulator screen sizes is not going to be a complete list of all screen sizes there will ever be. However, if those presets are truly all you want, check out table 1 in jmurphy's link. That leaves notification bar to be a bit of a wildcard unless you hide it with a theme.

Comment: Android Devices listed by DPI bucket: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a set size for the notification bar. Your best bet is to have a layout with height=fill_parent then take the height of that layout to do your calculations. That will give the content area only.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
int height= layout.getHeight();
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the notification bar height was always the same size.

Comment: It almost always is, but that can't be counted on

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so you got a list of all 10 (?) different sizes and write a handler for each one in your app.

Oh snap, Samsola made a new phone with a 823x584 resolution. Your app just broke!

Oh no! Cyanofonso made a custom ROM that has a new theme where the title bar is 2 pixels larger. Your app just broke!

To reiterate - whatever you're trying to do, don't do it. Either get the size at run-time, or (preferably) use dpi to make your app work on every possible device.

Answer (score 1):

You have the content sizes listed in your question unless i'm misunderstanding you. Perhaps this link will help you. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html